# Change this Loop by LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I got a string of 8 (It can be '.' or '0' or '1' at any position)
Example :

- 00000000
- .0111000
- 00010.00
- Etc...

i got this loop which is pretty straight forward:

```
        bool[] aBool= new bool[8];

        for (int i = 0; i <= _input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            switch (_input[i])
            {
                case zero:
                    aBool[i] = false;
                    break;

                case one:
                    aBool[i] = true;
                    break;

                case dot:
                    aBool[i] = null;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        return aBool;
```

return abool

How can i convert this in LINQ?

I made one for a string of only 0 or 1 and LINQ:

- return _input.Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();

But with the dot...

Thanks

Comment: That really isn't what LINQ does...

Comment: `aBool[i] = null;`?, if the array was `bool? [] aBool = new bool?[8];` then i could understand that statement but as it is now it wont compile.

Comment: So your real question is *"how do a take a binary string (with some non-binary characters) and convert it to an array of nullable bool?"*

Comment: Yea sorry: bool?[] aBool= new bool?[8];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple `Select` and `ToArray`:

```
  string _input = ".0111000";

  // Since you allow null, you have to switch to Nullable<bool> - bool?
  bool?[] aBool = _input
    .Select(c => 
         c == '1' ? (bool?) true 
       : c == '0' ? (bool?) false 
       : null)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sweet man! I'm getting this one since it's easier too read...Thanks!

Comment: You could also just use "var" and the type will be inferred.   
var aBool = _input.Select(etc etc).ToArray();

Answer (score 5):

```
input.Select(c => c == '.' ? (bool?)null : c == '1').ToArray();
```

Comment: Man that was quick! Totally working!Sorry i can't accept  more than 1 response , but this one was sweet too!